# Relative magnitude(s) of $x,y,z$ in hypothetical counterexamples to FLT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Let $0 < x < y < z$ be integers, and let $n \ge 1$ be an integer, such that $$x^n+y^n=z^n.  \tag{$\star$}$$ I’m hoping to find upper bounds on the magnitude $x/y$, either in terms of $n$ or otherwise. In his *13 Lectures on Fermat’s Last Theorem*, Ribenboim states that “$z,y$ are relatively close together and therefore the size of $x$ should be much smaller” — my goal is to find out *how much* smaller.

In *Fermat’s Last Theorem for Amateurs* [p. 199], Ribenboim references the following result of Catalan (1886):

> If $p$ is an odd prime, and $0 < x < y$ are integers such that $x^p + y^p = (y+1)^p$, then $x$ is the only integer such that $$\bigl(py^{\ p-1}\bigr)^{1/p} < x < \bigl(p(y+1)^{\ p-1}\bigr)^{1/p}.$$

Using this, one can get a bound *in that special case*. But as far as I can tell, this is the only explicit magnitude-based result in the whole book (other than trivial ones like $x+y>z$, *etc.*).

Perisastri (1969) showed that in ($\star$) we must have $z < x^2$.

What other results exist — or can be easily proven — with respect to the relative magnitude of the components of a hypothetical counterexample to the Fermat equation ($\star$), and in particular $x/y$?

Comment: Are you aware that FLT has been proved?

Comment: @mathguy: Yes I am.

Comment: So what are you asking for? An upper bound for the set of possible values of fractions that are known not to exist?

Comment: @mathguy: Prior to FLT being proven by Prof. Wiles, there were thousands and thousands of results proven with respect to hypothetical counterexamples. Some of them, I expect, discussed the relative magnitude of the component integers. I've asked for references. You don't have to answer if you don't want to.